# Why crop is not running?

Tags: android, crop

why the camera launches but the crop crash?
 I am not getting any error message. We followed http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/

```
package com.example.background;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener   {

    //keep track of camera capture intent
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    //keep track of cropping intent
    final int PIC_CROP = 2;
    //captured picture 
    private Uri picUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //retrieve a reference to the UI button
        Button captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        //handle button clicks
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
            try {
                //use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                //display an error message
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();
            }
            //user is returning from cropping the image
            else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
                //get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
                ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
                //display the returned cropped image
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }
        }
    }
```

is the problem here?

```
    private void performCrop(){
        try {
            //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                //indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
                //set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                //indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                //indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
                //retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your picUri is getting null. thats why its giving an error while cropping an captured image, So, refer this [link](http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/) to crop an images. its worked for me,
Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for a fact that this is what you are seeing, but unfortunately this Intent goes to the AOSP Camera app. Not all devices have it, and worse, it isn't in lollipop anymore.

I'm currently trying to figure out if there is an equivalent in the new picture editor app from google or if I really have to start using an external library for that...

A pity not to have such a standard feature available anymore.